# How to retrieve data through Foreign Key in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to retrieve data in Laravel.

I am having table user in which I m having field **parent_id** in which I m showing information of its  **user_id.**

Now I want to show information of logged user

I tried this

```
 {{Auth::user()->parent_id}}
```

I get the selected parent_id, now I want the name of that user_id.

I'm trying this

```
{{(Auth::user()->parent_id)->value('name')}}
```

Its getting an error.
Please tell me how can I write this in my code to get name of that parent id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do that.

1- Without relationship: you can select/find the user by `parent_id` and get its name. Something like this:

```
{{ App\User::find(Auth::user()->parent_id)->name }}
```

2- With relation: and I think it is easier. Define the relationship and set the `parent_id` as foreign key. Then you can get the parent user. Something like this:

```
{{ Auth::user()->parentUser->name }} // parentUser is the method created in User model
```

To define and use the relationship see the @Tharaka Dilshan answer.

Answer (score 3):

Define the relationship to the parent user in the `User` modal.

**User Modal**

```php
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

**blade**

```
{{ Auth::user()->parent->name }}
```